# TestLink API Python - How to look up test cases by assignee

Tags: python, testlink

I'd like to get the list of all test cases assigned to a specific user in TestLink. I'm using the [TestLink Python API, version 0.6.4](https://github.com/lczub/TestLink-API-Python-client). I've been reading the [JetMore docs for TestLink](http://jetmore.org/john/misc/phpdoc-testlink193-api/TestlinkAPI/TestlinkXMLRPCServer.html).

So far I have the following code:

```
from testlink import TestlinkAPIGeneric, TestLinkHelper
import testlink

TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_SERVER_URL = '<my testlink ip>'
TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_DEVKEY = '<my testlink devkey>'
my_test_link = TestLinkHelper(TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_SERVER_URL, TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_DEVKEY).connect(TestlinkAPIGeneric)

test_project_id = my_test_link.getTestProjectByName('<project name>')['id']
plans = my_test_link.getProjectTestPlans(test_project_id)
# I've also tried ['globalRoleID']
userid = int(my_test_link.getUserByLogin('<user name>')[0]['dbID'])
for plan in plans:
    print(my_test_link.getTestCasesForTestPlan(testplanid=plan['id'], assignedto=userid, details='full'))
```

This produces an empty list for every test plan in my project:

```
[]
[]
[]
...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't need userid at all. Instead of passing userid to assigned to pass username.
print(my_test_link.getTestCasesForTestPlan(testplanid=plan['id'], assignedto='username', details='full'))

Answer (score 0):

**assignedto** is an **optional parameter** in the function getTestCasesForTestPlan(). 
This function will always **return all** the testcases associated with the testplan. 
**Pass username instead of userid.** It will return all the testcases. 
To get testcases for specific user you have to modify the API code(xmlrpc.class.php) in testlink codebase.

Comment: If getTestCasesForTestPlan() will always return all of the test cases for the testplan, then what is the point of passing in any of the optional parameters?

Comment: I have tried the API for different users(even if user does not exist) but it always returns the same result. So the only way is to get desired result is to modify the api.